# how to get total sum of array of objects for logged in user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A user can add multiple products and multiple users can request that product. For each product I have an array of objects which holds the user ID's of the users who requested that product. I am trying to get a sum of all requests eg: (made up object id's for simplicity, I know they aren't realistic)

Below I have 2 products, one with a single request, and the second product with 2 requests, therefore this user has 2 products and 3 requests. I am trying to get the value of 3.

```
_id: ObjectId("12323443463")
userId: ObjectId("88888888")
title: "Product 1"
requests: Array
0: Object
_id: ObjectId("89766876")
userId: ObjectId("09795675")


_id: ObjectId("9878754")
userId: ObjectId("88888888")
title: "Product 2"
requests: Array
0: Object
_id: ObjectId("89766876")
userId: ObjectId("09795675")

1: Object
_id: ObjectId("66445547676")
userId: ObjectId("7765543434")
```

I tried this:

```
  Product.aggregate([
    { $match: { userId: req.user._id }},
    { $group: { _id: "$requests.userId", totals: { $sum: 1 } } }
  ])
```

If I console.log it I get:

```
[ { _id: [ 5c375260a6f58308e510711a, 5c25cddc73d10c02a75b3d55 ],
    totals: 1 },
  { _id: [ 5c375260a6f58308e510711a ], totals: 1 } ]
```

It is correct in that it gives me the 3 id's of the users that requested the product. However, I really just want the value of 3 as a result of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
Product.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "userId": req.user._id }},
  { "$group": { "_id": null, "totals": { "$sum": { "$size": "$requests" } } } }
])
```

Basically you need to [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the [**`$size`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the `requests` array

Comment: thank you. console.log() is giving me a value of 3. Why would someone downvote you for this answer??

Comment: just one thing though. This is giving me back an array. Since I only need the sum, is there a way to get it back so it isn't an array? I know I can access it like `console.log(product[0].totals);` but was just wondering.

Comment: No aggregation only returns as array. You have to go with the 0th index

Comment: Aha, I see. Thanks for the answer, it has helped me immensely.